# What does the command \@dblarg do in a class?

Tags: macros, latex-base

In the definition of a command appears the declaration of `\@dblarg`, as follows: `\def\title{\@dblarg\CJ@title}`. What exactly does `\@dblarg` do?

Comment: It's a kernel command: `\@dblarg{<command>}{<arg>}` will expand to `\{<command>}[<arg>]{<arg>}`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It essentially checks if the token after `\CJ@title` is `[` or not, in order to pass to the main command the same argument twice, if `[` is not found. The command `\CJ@title` must be defined by

```
\def\CJ@title[#1]#2{...}
```

so that, with a call such as

```
\title{xyz}
```

the expansions will be (successively}

```
\@dblarg\CJ@title{xyz}
...<some complex action>...
\CJ@title[{xyz}]{xyz}
```

and with a call such as

```
\title[abc]{xyz}
```

the expansions will be (successively}

```
\@dblarg\CJ@title[abc]{xyz}
...<some complex action>...
\CJ@title[abc]{xyz}
```

One can follow `...<some complex action>...` by looking at the definition of `\@dblarg`:

```
\long\def\@dblarg#1{\kernel@ifnextchar[{#1}{\@xdblarg{#1}}}
\long\def\@xdblarg#1#2{#1[{#2}]{#2}}
```

So with `\title{xyz}` one has (one step on each line, I omit the expansions of `\kernel@ifnextchar` that are irrelevant here)

```
\@dblarg\CJ@title{xyz}
\kernel@ifnextchar[{\CJ@title}{\@xdblarg{\CJ@title}}{xyz}
\@xdblarg{\CJ@title}{xyz}
\CJ@title[{xyz}]{xyz}
```

With `\title[abc]{xyz}` one has

```
\@dblarg\CJ@title{xyz}
\kernel@ifnextchar[{\CJ@title}{\@xdblarg{\CJ@title}}[abc]{xyz}
\CJ@title[abc]{xyz}
```

There's an extra pair of braces in the first case, but it will be removed by rule of TeX; it’s needed in case the title contains a `]`.

### How to do the same with `xparse`

With the `xparse` package one can obtain the same functionality with a clearer syntax (I assume this is done in a class or package file)

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\title}{om}{%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\CJ@title{#2}{#2}}
    {\CJ@title{#1}{#2}}%
}
\newcommand{\CJ@title}[2]{...}
```

So no delimited argument is necessary.

With a recent version of `xparse` one can do even better:

```
\RequirePackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\title}{O{#2}m}{%
  \CJ@title{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\CJ@title}[2]{...}
```

because with this code the value supplied for a missing optional argument is the same as the mandatory argument.

Comment: Instead of using the command `\def` by `\newcommand`, what would happen? Anything change?

Comment: @osjerick You can't define a command with delimited arguments with `\newcommand`, so `\def` is necessary.

Comment: Thanks @egreg, now I'm learning all about creating classes, you could recommend me a manual or book about this, please?

Comment: @osjerick In the "LaTeX companion" there's material about this.

Comment: Last question, why use `CJ` before `@`, what do that?

Comment: @osjerick: These are typically package-specific notations. Within the `.sty` file, `@` is treated like a letter. So, it could be that the package author prefix certain internal commands with their initials, or perhaps even an abbreviation of the package name. For example, the [`keyval` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/keyval) author (David Carlisle) decided to use a `KV@` prefix, which was duplicated in the [`xkeyval` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) using `XKV`.

Comment: +1 for being the first time I've ever seen macro expansion explained.

Answer (score 13):

This is an easy way of allowing optional arguments to some other function/macro.

For example, using your case of `\def\title{\@dblarg\CJ@title}`, you can either use

```
\title{some title}
```

*without* an optional argument, or use

```
\title[some optional title]{some title}
```

*with* an optional argument. "Easy" here refers to the fact that if you don't specify the optional component (like in the former example), it defaults to

```
\title[some title]{some title}
```

thereby converting single-argument responses into double-arguments. The macro `\CJ@title` is appropriately defined to manage both arguments and could have the form:

```
\def\CJ@title[#1]#2{%
  %...
}
```

This is typically the case with sectional commands that have an optional argument: `\section[<ToC entry>]{<body entry>}`. If you don't specify the optional argument, the `<body entry>` still makes its way into the ToC. How? `\@dblarg`.

Here are the formal definitions contained within [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) - you'll find its use inside `\@startsection`, just as an example:

```
\long\def\@dblarg#1{\kernel@ifnextchar[{#1}{\@xdblarg{#1}}}
\long\def\@xdblarg#1#2{#1[{#2}]{#2}}
```